# Main thread showing a form as dialog, how to close it programmatically by using worker thread?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to close a form showing as dialog by main thread. I am using beginInvoke to show that dialog and want to close or hide when worker thread complete its own task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as showing the form, for closing the form you can also use BeginInvoke() or Invoke().

```
form.Invoke(new Action(form.Close));
```

or if the code is inside the form itself, replace the **form** with **this**.

Comment: I have try both BeginInvoke() and Invoke() but no success.

Comment: Sorry. I provided the sample.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the BackgroundWorker, there is a event available: "OnRunWorkerCompleted" - It triggers if the worker has completed.

You can use this event to close your form.

Comment: I will try BackgroundWorker, but any other idea about worker thread which I am using?

Comment: What is a worker thread? You mean Thread? http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.thread.aspx